# Style Trigger using tabindex on tabcontrol is not working when itemsource is referenced

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have tabcontrol which uses an observable collection of tabitems as itemsource. I dont want the close button for the first tab alone. So i added the style trigger

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
<Grid Background="White">
<Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="#1b9ed2" Margin="6,0,12,0" Background="White">
<ContentPresenter Height="30" x:Name="ContentSite" ContentSource="Header" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,15,5,-5">
</ContentPresenter>
</Border>
<Button  Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Name="TabCloseButton" Click="TabCloseButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ToolTip="Close" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Padding="0">
<materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Close" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</Button>
</Grid>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
<Trigger Property="TabIndex" Value="0">
<Setter TargetName="TabCloseButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
</Trigger>
......
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
</Style>
</TabControl.Resources>
```

It works if i just added the items in xaml

```
<TabControl Name ="ConnectionsTab">
<TabItem Header="...." TabIndex="0"></TabItem>
<TabItem Header="...." TabIndex="1"></TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

But it doesn't works when I make the itemsource to the tabcontrol

```
private ObservableCollection<TabItem> tabItems = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();
```

inside constructor

```
tabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Connections", Content = new ResourceAccountDisplayUserControl(response), TabIndex = 0 });
ConnectionsTab.ItemsSource = tabItems;
```

I don't know why it does not work. Any idea or code to make it work will be helpful.

Comment: @Sinatr I have updated the complete code for the style. I used the setter inside the style. It works when i create tabitems directly in xaml. but not when i use itemsource

Comment: @Sinatr Actually my usecase is  "TabCloseButton" should not be visible for the first tab item alone.

Comment: What is `ConnectionsTab` and `tabItems` you are assigning as `ItemsSource`? Please refer to [mcve].

Comment: Generally speaking, `TabIndex` has nothing to do with the order of tabs in a tab control.

Comment: @grek40 but https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.tabcontrol.tabindex says that "TabIndex property to specify a control's place in the tab order on a form or report."

Comment: @Sinatr ConnectionsTab  is the name of the tab control

Comment: @Sinatr I have made the updated code

Comment: @pewex the "tab order" is the order, in which controls are focused when you press the `tab key` on your keyboard.

Comment: @grek40 thanks. I have added a number in the model to represent it and achieved the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `TabIndex` is not the index if your `TabItem` inside the `TabControl`. So, you need a different way to determine the actual tab position.

If your data source implements `IList`, you could for example write a `MultiValueConverter` that determines the position of an item within a collection:

```
public class MyTabItemIndexConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // TODO: add some validation to avoid unsupported values
        var c = (IList)values[1];
        return c.IndexOf(values[0]);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object values, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Side Note: there are probably other ways to determine the index like [Determining index of a tabitem](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/139bed8b-8eb0-4aec-a9c0-521bd7bede91/determining-index-of-a-tabitem?forum=wpf).

Then you can use this converter, to store the actual item index somewhere (or use it directly). In this example, I set the `TabItem.Tag` property to the item index:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyTabItemIndexConverter x:Key="tabItemIndexConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

[...]
<TabControl Name="tabControl1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Tag">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource tabItemIndexConverter}">
                        <Binding />
                        <Binding ElementName="tabControl1" Path="ItemsSource" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    [...]

</TabControl>
```

Now with `TabItem.Tag` you have a property that you can actually use in order to implement your trigger logic.